# TWIN PRIMES BETWEEN 2 VALUES wrong results

Tags: objective-c, c, while-loop, generic-programming

I've been working on this program to count how many twin primes between two values and it's been specified that twin primes come in the (6n-1, 6n+1) format, with the exception of (3, 5). My code seems to work fine, but it keeps giving me the wrong result....1 less couple of twin primes than i should get. Between 1 and 40, we should have 5 twin primes, but I'm always getting 4. é

What am I doing wrong? Am I not taking into account (3, 5)?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int prime (int num) { 
    int div;
    if (num == 2) return 1;
    if (num % 2 == 0) return 0;
    div = 3;
    while (div*div <= num && num%div != 0)
        div = div + 2;
    if (num%div == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int low, high, i, count, n, m;
    printf("Please enter the values for the lower and upper limits of the interval\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &low, &high);
    printf("THIS IS THE LOW  %d\n AND THIS IS THE HIGH %d\n", low, high);
    i = low;
    count = 0;
    while (6*i-1>=low && 6*i+1<=high) {
        n = 6*i-1;
        m = 6*i+1;
        if (prime(n) && prime(m)) ++count;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    printf("Number of twin primes is %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program misses (3 5) because 3 is not trapped as a prime number, and because 4 is not a multiple of 6. Rather than the main loop stepping by (effectively) 6, this answer steps by 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int prime (int num) { 
    int div;
    if (num == 1) return 0;             // excluded 1
    if (num == 2 || num == 3) return 1; // included 3 too
    if (num % 2 == 0) return 0;
    div = 3;
    while (div*div <= num) {
        if (num % div == 0)             // moved to within loop
            return 0;      
        div += 2;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int low, high, i, count, n, m;
    printf("Please enter the values for the lower and upper limits of the interval\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &low, &high);
    printf("THIS IS THE LOW  %d\n AND THIS IS THE HIGH %d\n", low, high);
    count = 0;
    for (i=low; i<=high; i++) {
        n = i-1;
        m = i+1;
        if (prime(n) && prime(m)) {
            printf ("%2d %2d\n", n, m);
            ++count;
        }
    }
    printf("Number of twin primes is %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
1
40
THIS IS THE LOW  1
 AND THIS IS THE HIGH 40
 3  5
 5  7
11 13
17 19
29 31
Number of twin primes is 5
```

Next run:

```
3
10
THIS IS THE LOW  3
 AND THIS IS THE HIGH 10
 3  5
 5  7
Number of twin primes is 2
```

Comment: It all works perfectly for intervals like 1 and 40, but not for 3 and 10. Between 3 and 10, i should have 2, not 1 twin...but that's not the output I get.

Comment: Entering 3 and 10, gives two pairs (3,5) and (5,7).

Answer (score 0):

https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/100ktwins.txt

The five twin primes under forty are (3,5), (5,7), (11,13), (17,19), (29,31) so if you know that your code isn't counting (3,5) then it is working correctly, counting (5,7), (11,13), (17,19), and (29,31).

A possible fix would be to add an if-statement which adds 1 to "count" if the starting number is less than 4. I'm not really that used to reading C syntax so I had trouble getting my head around your formulas, sorry.

edit: since comments don't format code snippets:

`i = low;
    count = 0;
    if (low <= 3 && high >= 3){
        count ++;  // accounts for (3,5) twin primes if the range includes 3
    }`

Comment: I tried adding an if statement to count if the starting number is less than 4, less or equal to  5 and equal to 3. It works for when i have intervals that start with 1, such as 1 and 10, 1 and 100 and 1 and 1000000, but when I try intervals like between 3 and 10, it still counts one less twin than it should.

Comment: The statement I added before my while loop was the following:
    if (low<= 5) count = 1;

Comment: Ok, so it definitely has to do with the unique distance between (3,5) and (5,7). The formula can't account for it because of this so you have to count it manually if your entered range includes three. I inserted the following if-statement and it works correctly:
`    i = low;
    count = 0;
    if (low <= 3 && high >= 3){
        count ++;  // accounts for (3,5) twin primes if the range includes 3
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your prime function, this is the output of your prime function for the first ten prime evaluations

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++) printf("%d\t%d",i,prime(i));

1       1
2       1
3       0
4       0
5       1
6       0
7       1
8       0
```

Note the prime() function from Weather Vane, you should include 3 as prime (and exclude 1).

---

From [1], twin primes are the ones that have a prime gap of two, differing by two from another prime.

Examples are (3,5) , (5,7), (11,13). The format (6n-1,6n+1) is true but for (3,5) as you stated. Your program runs almost ok since it shows the number of twin primes that are in the interval AND follows the rule mentioned above. This doesn't include (3,5). You can make a kind of exception (like if low<=3 add 1 to total count), or use another algorithm to count twin primes (like verify if i is prime, then count distance from i to next prime, if distance=2 then they are twin primes)

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime